# Passing undefined to jquery val function

Tags: jquery

my code:

```
<select id="carlist">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

function getVal(e, v) {
    return e.val(v);
}

var elem=$('#carlist');

alert(elem.val()); // returns volvo
alert(getVal(elem)); // returns [Object Object]
```

I expected both alerts to print the same, however the second one fails, is this a jquery bug ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9a36epa/)

Comment: You're setting the value to `undefined`, and whenever you set a value with `val()` it returns the jQuery object for further chaining, and not the value, and that's why you're getting `[Object Object]`, it's the jQuery object, and as `alert` is not a debugging tool, it can't properly show it.

Comment: @adeneo This should be an answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a lead from JCOC611 I ended up tracing into jQuery code. The issue is that when jQuery checks if val received arguments or not it's checking the number of arguments, so passing undefined to val() still invokes the overload that receives a parameter.

So the right way to write a proxy to a function like jQuery's val() is:

```
function getVal(e, v) {
   return arguments.length>1 ? e.val(v) : e.val();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getVal(e, v)
```

has 2 params and you are passing one and e.val(v) should be e.val()

it should be like

```
function getVal(e) {
return e.val();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As to why this behaviour makes sense: in jQuery, you can either call `e.val()` with no arguments, and it will return the current value attribute of the element *e*, or call it with one, `e.val(newVal)` in order to set a new value. If you use the latter, jQuery will return the **element**, in order to make chaining possible.

Even if you are calling your function `getElement` with no second argument, it will still differentiate between `undefined` and no argument, and thus will set the value of the element to undefined, rather than return the current value.

If you want to overload your function, you can use:

```
function getVal(e, v) {
    if(v === undefined){
       return e.val();
    else{
       return e.val(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `v` inside your returned method. And you are using passing one argument in your function, so you may opt to remove `v`

```
function getVal(e) {
    return e.val(); // < remove 'v' here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getVal(e, v) {
    return e.val(v);
}
```

Should be

```
function getVal(e) {
    return e.val();
}
```